# Regex for bytes separated by : problem

Tags: java, regex

I have on input hex four byte values separated by : (something like  aabbccdd:ffffffff:aaccbbff ).
How to construct regex in Java which is going to give answer if input is in correct format or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for this: `^([0-9a-fA-F]{8}:)*([0-9a-fA-F]{8})$`

Optional 8 HEX digits followed by a colon (`:`). Ending with a group without the colon. Probably a way to reduce the RegEx.

Answer (score 6):

How about this?

```
String value = "aabbccdd:ffffffff:aaccbbff";
boolean match = value.matches("\\p{XDigit}{8}(:\\p{XDigit}{8})*");
// ...
```

The `\p{XDigit}` equals to `[0-9a-fA-F]` by the way. See also the [`java.util.regex.Pattern` javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: "\\p{XDigit}{8}(?::\\p{XDigit}{8})*" would be better - no unnecessary group capturing

Answer (score 1):

You might try this for arbitrary sequences of 4 bytes: `[0-9a-fA-F]{8}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{8})*`